# mysql: Group By using date_created in quartlerly report with DATE_FORMAT or quarter() functions

Tags: mysql

In my project, a monthly report is being generated for the revenue/sales from the client orders.
Here is the sql fiddle for how my current report generation is working.
Monthly report sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ca03a/7

Query for monthly report:

```
SELECT SUM(price) as `Ordered total $`, date_created,
DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%X - %b') as `Month`, COUNT(*) as `Total Orders` 
FROM orders WHERE class_id IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%X-%m');
```

**Now I need to modify it to generate the report on quarter basis instead of monthly.**

I have found i can use mysql `quarter()` function. I have tried using it but it did not work as intended.
Here is what I have tried Quarter sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ca03a/6

Query for quarter report which I have tried:

```
SELECT SUM(price) as `Ordered total $`, date_created,
 quarter(date_created) as `Quarter`,
 COUNT(*) as `Total Orders` 
 FROM orders WHERE class_id IN (1,2)
 GROUP BY
 quarter(date_created);
```

The mysql `quarter()` function is not getting records for quarters of all the years as you can see in my second sqlfiddle.

Is there any way to modify `DATE_FORMAT()` function to get quarter reports? Or How can I use `quarter()` function of mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`YEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function to get the year from the date and [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) that to the quarter to give you a year/quarter value that you can group by:

```
SELECT SUM(price) as `Ordered total $`, date_created,
CONCAT(YEAR(date_created), ' - ', QUARTER(date_created)) as `Quarter`,
COUNT(*) as `Total Orders` 
FROM orders WHERE class_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY `Quarter`
```

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ca03a/12)

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Comment: @Haroon no problem at all. I just wanted to make sure that you didn't need any more help with the question.